# apply css to after element last child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a requirement where I need to `remove the last border of an element`, but the border is applied using the `after` element.

My code :

```
<div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
</div>

.abc::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

I've tried `removing the border` for after element using the below code, but not working.

```
.abc:after:not([style*="display: none"]):last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Is this possible using this approach? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sozs6sr/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.abc:last-child:after{
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the selector you're using is that it's invalid, according to the specifications for pseudo-elements:

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors that represents the subjects of the selector.
>   <sub>https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#pseudo-elements</sub>

Therefore your selector is invalid; and should instead be:

```
.abc:after:not([style*="display: none"]):last-child
```

Instead, because you're styling the pseudo-element for the `:last-child` element, you should use:

```
.abc:last-child::after
```

```css
.abc::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.abc:last-child::after {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.abc::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.abc:last-child::after {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
  <div class="abc">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this, if you don't go with `after` then:

```
.abc{
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.abc:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```